# storing umbraco:item fields into the xsl:variable

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I want to use creationDate field in my template in umbraco.

I know that i can extract this field with this 
`<umbraco:Item field="createDate" runat="server" />`
but I want to store this data as a xsl:variable and manipulate it.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of a node's attributes and properties are automatically available in your XSLT macros through a variable called `currentPage`. So, in your macro simply use the following line:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="myDate" select="$currentPage/@createDate" />
```

Should you wish to then format the date, use the function provided by the `umbraco.library` extension, like so:

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:FormatDateTime($myDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy')" />
```

If you need more precise manipulation over your date var, look into the `Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes` extension that comes packaged with Umbraco. There's about forty-odd functions in there, too.